# How to append x-header information in generated .eml / .msg file

Tags: eml

My requeriment is to open the email content to,cc,subject,body, attachement retrive from DB and open the content in user email client ( Outlook ).

To achieve this i'm creating .eml/.msg file with the retrieved information and saving into the local disk and opening the .eml file, all this flow happens programmatically in C#. But when the content opened in  outlook email client it opens as send mode( Although when opening a email to read/send).

I want to open the email in differnet mode Compose/ Reply/ Forward. When i gone through many article understand have to add x-header when generating the .eml file will do the magic. But i'm sure how to achieve this solution.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Headers.Add("X-Unsent", "1");
```